# How to concatenate in xquery for loop

Tags: function, loops, concatenation, xquery

I found the solution, so I don't need more help this moment,
thank you for everyone.
Problem was, because I don't know this language, well.

But needs to put for example
so, principally curly brackets were necessary
return  {

for $n in 1 to 10
(: concatenate something here)

```
      return $something
```

}

and the resolved problem is below

how to concatenate in a function, (finally I do it with attributes),
but first I would like to resolve this

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
'use strict';
 
declare function local:Do_the_string($t as xs:string)  as xs:string{
   (:t is wanted node:)
 
(: below is a temporal loop, I don´t know how to fix it and return concatenated value"
 let $test2 := "ll"
  let $data := 
   for $n in 1 to 10
           (: concatenate something here:)
          
          return $n
   
 (: let $row_information := "AAAA2" if I use this line; this works:)  

 return $data
 
 };
```

if I test it:

`declare function local:Do_the_string($t as xs:string) as xs:string{`

ERROR: [1.0-ml] XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) local:Do_the_string("/my/path/test.xml") -- Invalid coercion: ("test21", "test22", "test23", ...) as xs:string

#MODIFIED LINE  `return concat ("test2", $n)`

Comment: Can you share any output you are getting from running this code? Including any errors? Please share this in your Question by editing it.

Comment: Hi, I have you seen the modification. there are error results

Comment: Does Marklogic support `string-join`? Then try `string-join((1 to 10)!concat('test2', .), ' ')` or `string-join(for $i in (1 to 10) return concat('test2', $i), ' ')`.

Comment: Hi, thank you, This is is resolved already. I don't know if I have to mark this as resolved some way.  however I think Marklogic supports also string join. however I resolved my asked problem with adding one html this and curly brackets this way return beginning_html_tag { loop and concatenation }ending_html_tag.

Comment: You should be able to add your own solution as an answer and accept it, to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: thank you I did so

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

return beginning_html_tag { loop and concatenation }ending_html_tag

Curly brackets were necessary

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
'use strict';
    declare function local:Do_the_string($t as xs:string)  as xs:string{
  
   (:let $test2 := $t:)
 
  return <test> {
     for $n in 1 to 10
         
         return fn:concat ($n,",")
  
 
 }</test>
 };
 let $test as xs:string := ""

 let $test :=  local:Do_the_string("what_ever")

 return $test
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).